# How to get access to url (or grails params) outside of the controller?

Tags: grails

**Background:** 
I created my own TagLib for application. One of the tags must depend on current request URL (on path & url parameters).
I have two gsp files - layout and regular page.

**The issue:** 
I tried to get current request url from tag handler using this:

```
request.requestURI
```

But instead of what I have in browser

```
http://localhost:8888/gbv/999/index
```

For some reason it will return something like this, when tag invoked from regular page:

```
/gbv/grails/index.dispatch
```

And it will return this, when tag invoked from template (which is ok):

```
/gbv/999/index
```

**Question:**
How to do one (or both of this)

1. Get the same instance of "params" which is accessible from controller (without modifying the controller)
2. Get current request url (the same as user have in the browser)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to get a reference to the parameters simply by referencing `params` within the tag class.

If you want to re-construct the full path of a request (as shown in the browser), you can do this using methods of the `request` object, which is an instance of [HttpServletRequest](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html), e.g.

- getContextPath()
- getRequestURI()
- getServerName()
- getServerPort()

Comment: Thank you!
Actually it was very simple. Just use "params". All current parameters already there. 
BTW: non of the other options are helpful.

Comment: Nope, this does NOT work. "params" is not available in the model. I'm still searching for a working solution.

Comment: @Panique I didn't say it was available in the model (domain class), I said it was available in a TagLib. Params is also available in a controller or GSP

Answer (score 3):

use the following

`request.forwardURI`

Answer (score 0):

use `${params.id}` to get the id of the current item you are viewing.

---

Also,
use `${controllerName}` to get Controller Name.
use `${actionName}` to get Action Name